# Access undefined field of a class in PHP

Tags: php

I was recently reading a few articles on PHP Object oriented programming and came across something like this:

```
class a {}
$temp = new a();
$temp->newfiled = 20;    // This field is not present within the class
```

The above code works fine in PHP 5.3

Why dosent PHP throw an error? I am coming from Java background in which we can only use fields that have been defined within a class.

**Update:** Edited php.ini to error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT, but it continues to hide errors.

**Also, is this a feature of PHP?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: PHP is not Java. Slightly longer: PHP is dynamic type, whereas Java is a static typed language.
However, you could raise your error-level. You should see a notice, or (strict-)warning.

http://php.net/language.oop5.properties

Comment: edited php.ini to error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT, but it continues to hide errors, Also, is this a feature of PHP?

Comment: @Akash As mentioned in the answer: A kind of. It's its nature.

Comment: This is a feature. You may define on the fly by your needs properties. Personally I found this usefull. PHP is not a strong typical language. However, sometimes you may meet difficulties, for example you miss spell one letter in a property name, and PHP eat this without problems.

Comment: @Marcodor thanks, was finding it useful in some applictions :D

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this may be an advantage.

You may use [property_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) function if you need to be sure that property are explicitly declared or are declared in ancestor class.